# window.open and add property to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

i have code in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function createDialogBox()
{
var dialogBox = window.open("in1.html");
dialogBox.nameBox= "my little box"
}

window.onload = createDialogBox;
window.onclick = createDialogBox;//when event is click evrything is okand i can get nameBox from in1.html via window.nameBox
</script>
</head>
<body>
Parent Page
</body>
</html>
```

DialogBox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
console.log(window.nameBox)// undefined
</script>
<body>
DialogBox Page
</body>
</html>
```

why i cant get nameBox when i try to load in1.html and use window.onload? Both file are in my computer and run directly file. Both file are in the same folder

Comment: `window.open("in1.html","nameBox"/*,[,options]*/);`

Comment: no it is not good for me. "namebox" is my custom name. I want to add property into dialogBox and i want to get this property on new window

Comment: if you wana pass variable from `index.html` to `popup.html` set variable `var nameBox = 'my little box';` in `index.html` and to get variable from `popup.html` use `window.parent.nameBox`

Comment: no, i dont have any errors.

function createDialogBox()
{
var dialogBox = window.open("in1.html");
dialogBox.nameBox= "my little box"
}
window.onclick = createDialogBox;

Comment: i want to add property to dialogBox like dialogBox.myProperty. But if i set property ang go to load dialogBox via bony.onLoad i get undefined. When i use window.onclick everything is ok.

Comment: Yep! , i'm sorry your code i tested locally and it works with onload, onclick !!

Comment: on Firefox you tested?

Comment: No thats chrome

Comment: **Note:** your popup page should logs `undefined` if you refresh that

Comment: In IE 8 and firefox not works with onload but witch onclick it working, can you tell me why?

Comment: Do you have multi `window.onload` event in the same page?

Comment: Do you test it with `file:///` or `http://` protocol

Comment: file:/// is any diffrence?

Comment: strange that it works with onclick and does not work with onload

Comment: Try to run server locally such as Wamp Server, using node-webkit browser or deploy online, should work.

Answer (score -1):

actually your are creating an object of `window.open("in1.html");`
if you want to name parent page name box try this

```
 function createDialogBox() {
            var dialogBox = window.open("HtmlPage2.html");
            dialogBox.nameBox = "my little box"
            this.nameBox="parent little box"
        }
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'nameBox' of undefined`

Comment: no no no ;d.
i want to set property on dialogBox.nameBox and i want to get this property when i load dialog box, but i cant get undefined when event is body.load

Comment: i am not sure, you might have pop up disabled for this site, that could be the reason your are getting 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'nameBox' of undefined'

Comment: so, why its working with window.onclick ?
it only dosent work when i use body.onload or window.onload.

Comment: don't know the exact reason why it works with window.onclick, mostly all the  modern browser will block if any pop up or new tab which is not intended by the user or done in the background (considered as bad popups) , typically this requires user to click or do some action in order to allow (considered as good popups)